# The value returned from a custom attribute is undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined

I am avoiding the use of `$(this).attr()` to get the values of custom elements, and I have read up that should you need a custom element, you should prefix it with `data-` and use `$(this).data()` to access the contents of that element (in my case, it is dynamically populated into the element as the element is part of a set of dynamic elements)

My question is fairly simple.

```
<a id="' + node.Id + '" data-currentValue='+node.Name+' class="button icon-pencil with-tooltip" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Edit" onclick="UpdateAttributes($(this).data(\'currentValue\'), $(this).attr(\'id\'));"</a>
```

I logged the values to the console after capturing them, but unsurprisingly, the `$(this).data()` part returns undefined (value should be in this tested case `"asdf"`) , and the id returns the value I expected it to return (in my case, `2000046`).

What is wrong with this element? I cannot spot where things have gone wrong, I have no idea why it throws undefined, and I need the value within `data-currentValue`. Any Ideas and insights to share so I can get the value I need from `data-currentValue`?

Dynamic element as a whole:

```
    $("#tblAttributes tbody").empty();
    var tableContents = [];
    $.each(data.KeyValuePairs, function (i, node) {
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<tr>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<p>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = node.Name;
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</p>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<span class="button-group compact">';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<a id="' + node.Id + '" data-currentValue='+node.Name+' class="button icon-pencil with-tooltip" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Edit" onclick="UpdateAttributes($(this).data(\'currentValue\'), $(this).attr(\'id\'));"</a>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<a id="' + node.Id + '" class="button red-gradient icon-trash with-tooltip confirm" href="javascript:DeleteAttribute('+node.Id+');" title="Delete" </a>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</span>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</tr>';
    });
    $("#AttributeCount").html(data.KeyValuePairs.length);
    $("#tblAttributes tbody").append(tableContents.join(""));
```

**Edit**

So this approach I had in mind was clumsy and cumbersome (thanks to BlazeMonger confirming that .data() tries to convert everything to primitive types, so I have changed my code to use an associative array instead to access the information where I need it. I no longer need custom attributes in the elements.

```
var attributes = {}; //associative array declared globally
...


$("#tblAttributes tbody").empty();
    var tableContents = [];
    attributes = {};
    $.each(data.KeyValuePairs, function (i, node) {
        attributes[node.Id] = node; //associating the node's id with the node for future use
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<tr>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<p>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = node.Name;
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</p>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<span class="button-group compact">';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<a id="' + node.Id + '" class="button icon-pencil with-tooltip" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Edit" onclick="UpdateAttributes(' + node.Id +');"</a>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '<a id="' + node.Id + '" class="button red-gradient icon-trash with-tooltip confirm" href="javascript:DeleteAttribute('+node.Id+');" title="Delete" </a>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</span>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</td>';
        tableContents[tableContents.length] = '</tr>';
    });
...
        function UpdateAttributes( attrId) {
        console.log(attributes[attrId].Name); //now I can access the information I needed which was to be stored as a custom attribute in the <a> element.
```

Comment: tableContents[tableContents.length] = 'value' can be written as tableContents.push('value'), just thought I'd give you that pointer. Other than that, I strongly suggest you consider templating like Mustache instead of building your object like that

Comment: we only do it this way so we dont have to Append Append Append. Its our company standard way

Comment: also seems to squeeze a tiny bit of performance out of this code. just saying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.data()` method retrieves the `data-` HTML attributes once, at page load. After that, you can alter the `data-` attributes but it won't change what's retrieved by `data()`.

Instead, use `.data(name,value)` to set new values that `.data(name)` will retrieve. (Note also that this will not alter the `data-` HTML attributes at the same time. You can change one or the other.)

It might be useful for jQuery to have some way to automatically pull the current `data-` attributes into `data()` variables at once, but as of jQuery 1.9 no such built-in functionality exists. Shouldn't be hard to write one, though.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: I have my concerns about data though because it seems to behave so that it tries to convert everything to a primitive type. I might be wrong though

Comment: Yes, it does -- it attempts to intelligently convert string values into integers, floats, arrays, or objects. If you don't want it to do that, access the `data-` attributes directly through `.attr()` and they will always be read as strings.

Comment: With that confirmed, I would rather assign the nodes here to an global associative array, that way I would be storing the information in-memory (won't ever go more than 5 objects, as we induced limits), and still be able to access the items a way lot faster. I learned something today :)